# Why does my python list comprehension raise a NameError?

Tags: python, list-comprehension, nameerror

Why doesn't the following list comprehension expression work?

```
M = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
N = [[2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4]]

[col1 * col2 for (col1, col2) in zip(row1, row2) for (row1, row2) in zip(M, N)]
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/path/to/file.py", line 4, in <module>
    [col1 * col2 for (col1, col2) in zip(row1, row2) for (row1, row2) in zip(M, N)]
NameError: name 'row1' is not defined
```

Comment: You are referencing `row1` and `row2` before telling the interpreter what they are.

Comment: `[col1*col2 for (row1, row2) in zip(M,N) for (col1, col2) in zip(row1, row2)]`  try this comprehension

Comment: ah i see, the for statement should be put in revert order. THanks

Comment: @jAckOdE Actually it was *you* that wrote the loops backwards. The idea of a list comprehension is that `[x for y in A for z in B]` represents the loop: `for y in A: for z in B: the_list.append(x)`. No idea why you think the equivalent statement should swap the loops.

Comment: @Bakuriu Because the whole thing is swapped comparing to loops, one might be tempted to think the same of the order of nested `for` statements in a comprehension as well.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, `row1` is not defined and so is `row2`.

Let's simplify what you're actually trying to do:

```
for row1, row2 in zip(M, N):
    for col1, col2 in zip(row1, row2):
        result = col1 * col2
        print result
```

The above code works fine because we first selected `row1` and `row2` from `zip(M, N)`. And then we selected `col1` and `col2` from `zip(row1, row2)`.

So if you want to compress the code in one single line, you **will** have to follow the same approach as above. So your code will look something like below:

```
[col1 * col2 for (row1, row2) in zip(M, N) for (col1, col2) in zip(row1, row2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume what you wanted to type is this:

```
[[col1*col2 for (col1,col2) in zip(row1,row2)] for (row1,row2) in zip(M,N)]
```

Zip the sublists in the outer loop/outer list comprehension and in the inner one, zip those sublists and multiply the elements.

```
>>> [[col1*col2 for (col1,col2) in zip(row1,row2)] for (row1,row2) in zip(M,N)]
[[2, 4, 6], [12, 15, 18], [28, 32, 36]]
```